# Twitter Api library? + retweeing

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter, twitter-feed

I am looking at the twitter api page https://dev.twitter.com/ and I noticed that they have already built libraries that are wrappers against the twitter api. So I am thinking this is the best way to go but I am unsure which C# library I should use.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

What I am trying to do is make some simple service or cmd line application that will help me automate retweeting.

So I am looking for a library that will allow me to get posts from other twitter accounts and then retweet them from another account.

I am not sure if the library can do this or not. Otherwise I was thinking of getting the RSS feed from the twiter account I want to get the twitters from parse out the new ones and use a library to retweet them on my own account.

I have not used twitter much so I am hopping someone can shed some light on this.

Comment: I'm about to look at this and am interested in any comments that people have about the different ones.

Comment: I wrote the Twitter Api in Java (even though there are some available online). It was for me to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am currently in the process of expanding the new re-write of Twitterizer (http://code.google.com/p/twitterizer), once the proper methods have been added to the new version, you should be able to do this in a fairly straight forward way.

1. Get the user timeline of the user you want to retweet.
2. Locate the tweet (aka status).
3. Call the retweet method.

Here are the raw API calls you'll probably need:

1. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline
2. (step 2 doesn't have an API call)
3. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/retweets/%3Aid

If you're in a time crunch, I can probably get those particular methods created quite quickly, as the underpinnings of our library is ready to go. Just let me know.

No matter what direction you choose, be absolutely sure to use OAuth for user authorization. (That's what we just re-wrote Twitterizer) Basic authentication will cease to function sometime in June. (Details here: http://groups.google.com/group/twitter-api-announce/browse_thread/thread/c2c4963061422f28?hl=en)

Comment: I am in no rush. Just give me a ETA and that will be fine. I rather let you guys do your job right and have good documentation then you guys trying to get it out fast and it is buggy and no documentation. I can live doing it manually. Maybe this can be your first tutorial lol I bet alot of people want a feature like this.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the list I'd the first appears to be most comprehensive. However the linq 2 Twitter seems to be promising for the reading stuff.